# Some NSNotification.Name constants are missing when enabling C++ interoperability

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

When enabling direct C++ interoperability in Xcode, this simple code below

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(subjectAreaDidChange(_:)),
                                       name: .AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange,
                                       object: nil)
```

gives me the following error

```
Type 'NSNotification.Name?' has no member 'AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange'
```

But if I switch `C++ and Objective-C interoperability` to just `C / Objective-C` then the code compiles without errors.

The issue seems to affect `NSNotification.Name` constants only from `AVFoundation` framework (although there maybe more).

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Apparently the error is related to the fact that compiler can't find the constant despite the fact that the framework was already imported, note the error message carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

It’s a known bug (https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733693) for Xcode 15.

You can work it around by using raw strings of needed notifications:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(subjectAreaDidChange),
                                       name: .init(rawValue: "AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification"),
                                       object: nil)
```

**Long answer**

If you look inside `AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h` you can find:

```objectivec
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification API_AVAILABLE(ios(5.0), macCatalyst(14.0), tvos(17.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos, visionos) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos);
```

The interoperability just looks for “Notification” suffix in exported strings and converts them to `NSNotification.Name` e.g.:

```
AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification -> NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange
```

The same works for strings in your app:

```objectivec
// Test.h
extern NSString *const MyNotification;

// Test.m
NSString *const MyNotification = @"MyNotification";
```

Then you can write in your swift file:

```swift
let notification: NSNotification.Name = .My
```

But it works for `C / Objective-C` only and doesn't for `C++ / Objective-C++` because the compiler doesn't generate appropriate properties in `NSNotification.Name` extension, for instance:

```swift
extension NSNotification.Name {
    ...    
    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    public static let AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange: NSNotification.Name
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I wonder my google-fu didn't work with this question. Just to be sure: raw strings do match with their constants, right? Because I am worried that I won't be able to get some of those notifications.

Comment: You can get the string values by `print(NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange.rawValue)`, but usually its the same property name plus "Notification" suffix.